# Is it possible to (easily?) re-write the paths within a Mercurial Queue patch?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I've got some MQ patches with work implemented in file path `project/feature_a`, but I need to move these changes to `project/feature_b`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to modify the patch files directly with a tool or an editor.

You must (of course) do this while the patches are unapplied, so begin with

```
$ hg qpop -a
```

Then edit the patches in `.hg/patches` using either an editor of your choice or perhaps by using [filterdiff from patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/). Running

```
$ filterdiff --strip 3 \
             --addoldprefix a/project/feature_b/ \
             --addnewprefix b/project/feature_b/ your-patch
```

might do the trick by stripping off the old `a/project/feature_b` prefixes before adding new ones.

Comment: I thought that might be the only way. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles upon this question, make sure your editor does not remove trailing spaces when editing patch files (like mine did). I had spaces in my path, which means the `---` and `+++` lines have to end with a `TAB`.